# why this c++ template specialization doesn't work for me

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this piece of code, I would expect that `Vec v` would be deduced to the specialization template of `Vec`. Instead, I got a compiling error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25:9: error: class template argument deduction failed:
     Vec v;
         ^
main.cpp:25:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘Vec()’
main.cpp:13:7: note: candidate: template Vec()-> Vec
 class Vec{
       ^~~
main.cpp:13:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:25:9: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
     Vec v;
         ^
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int N>
class Vec{
    T _v[N];
};

template<>
class Vec<float, 4>{
    float _v[4];
};


int main()
{
    Vec v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Vec` is a template, it needs template arguments if you want to instantiate it.

Comment: Yeah, but I have a specialization version of template `Vec<float, 4>`, so when I do `Vec v` , I would expect it matches the specialization, not asking me to instantiate it again.

Comment: Why should it? Would you expect `std::vector v;` to instantiate a `std::vector<bool>`? What if you had several different specializations?

Comment: A specialization does not mean default values for the parameters, it means a different template implementation for those parameters. By the way, your specialization does not really specialize anything - the resulting template is the same as it would be without the specialization.

Comment: If you want to omit the parameters, you could declare `typedef Vec4f = Vec<float, 4>` and use `Vec4f`.

Comment: I think I have a misunderstanding regarding to the specialization. I regard `specialization` as the `default parameters to template`. Thank you guys for clarifying this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused specializations with default template arguments. Specializations are used to write implementations of functions/classes that handle specific cases where template arguments match some sort of pattern.

This is how you'd achieve what you actually want:

```
template<class T = float, std::size_t N = 4>
class Vec
{
    T _v[N];
};

int main()
{
    Vec<> v;
}
```

This might not make sense for a vector class like this. Something like `using Vec4f = Vec<float, 4>;` might be more fitting, as people have commented.